# Looking for a better multi-key solution

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures

So I've looked at Dictionaries and various arrays for this, and I'm sure I'm missing an elegant solution.

Currently, I have a configuration dictionary that has information about what data needs to be retrieved.

Then I create a string[,] array where the first string is the item number and the second is the configuration value for a given item, then the value is the value for that configuration item.  Something like this:

```
ret[0,0] = "12345678"
ret[0,1] = "\\localhost\images"
ret[0,2] = "\test.img"
ret[1,0] = "23231231"
ret[1,1] = "\\localhost\images"
ret[1,2] = "\here.img"
```

There are more values, but that's the gist of it.

Now I need to also to grab each of those .img files (which are concatenated TIFF files) and extract images into byte[] values.  Some of the additional values are an offset and length in the file for that item number's image, so extracting the images is easy.  For some reason, however, I'm having a hard time finding a smart way to index the byte[] arrays for a given image (there's a front and a rear image for each) with the index value of the ret[,] array.  Neither Dictionaries or Lists seem like they'd work.  If I could have a jagged array with mixed values, that would work, but I don't really see how to do that.

Please let me know if I'm not making sense regarding what I'm looking for.  I may need to draw it out lol

Thanks!

Comment: What about a list of instances of a class you create?

Comment: If i hear "better multi-key", jagged arrays  or `ret[,]` i always think: class. A class can contain anything and you don't need to fiddle around with dimensions. You have meaningful properties.

Comment: I guess this is just a bit beyond my current knowledge level - but challenges are the only way to learn, right?  Do you have any recommendations for books or webpages that would get me started down this path?  C# isn't my strong suit, though this app I've been writing for a year has increased my knowledge considerably, there's still a lot of chinks in the armor on this one.  Thanks!

Edit:  Something like this?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xth2y6ft(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need something like:

```
Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,<string>> myVar = new Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,string>>();
myVar.add(0,new Dictionary<int,string>(0,'string'));
Console.WriteLine(myVar[0][0]);
```

You might also want to check the DataTable class.

Comment: I was considering this.  The current dictionary I use for configuration is a Dictionary<string, object> dict so that I can store basically anything in the object, which has been very handy.  The nested dictionaries like this, however, get to be a bit messy when the final value isn't always the same type (obj).

Comment: @JesseWilliams you could do `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,<object>> myVar = new Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,object>>();` That way you can have keys that get you the right set of configuration settings, then that has keys, which have values that are objects

Comment: @Prescott - I was considering that.  I was just wondering if there was a more elegant solution.  My other concern is that the first int will come from the call each time, the second int will be static (always the same number), and the object will vary for each item.

So, if I create the dictionary, I suppose I could just loop for each item?  The first int picks up the loop count, then builds each entry...  Hmmm...

Comment: A more detailed example that shows the variety of your data, and we might have a better solution - this sounds like a very specific implementation problem - and as always, there are many ways to pull it off.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define your own class for the image.

It stores the number, and all the other strings and the byte array. Then you implement a List of this class.